# How to write MongoDB query to filter selectively

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a query where we have 2 types of employees stored in a database.  I want a list of all the employees sorted by their start date, but if an employee is on ‘contract’ then I want to include only those employees whose end date is still in future.

Example of such a collection would be:

```
{
  "_id": 123,
  "startDate": some date
  "endDate": some date
  "type": “FULL_TIME",
},
{
  "_id": 123,
  "startDate": some date
  "endDate": some date
  "type": “CONTRACT",
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below `$or` find query.

First condition to get all active `CONTRACT` employees and second part to get all `FULL_TIME` employees followed by `asc` sorting on  `startDate`.

```js
db.collection.find(
  { $or:
    [
      { $and:
        [
          { type: "CONTRACT" }, 
          { endDate: { $gt: new ISODate() } }
        ]
      },
      { type:"FULL_TIME" }
    ]
  }
).sort( { startDate: 1 } );
```